# Displaying an image on top of a picturebox

Tags: c#, drawing, 2d-games

So at the basis of things I'm creating a Pacman game.

I am currently able to get the map displaying (created own map using c# graphics, (located in Cell.cs but irrelevant to this question.))

I'm currently stuck on how to get the Pacman displaying onto the map but struggling immensely. My "MovingPacman" file does not seem to be able to find the picturebox that is on my form (the form itself is called "Gameboard" and the picturebox is called "mapPictureBox").

But to be honest these errors might not even matter as I'm not even sure if I am going the correct way about displaying and moving the pacman.

Any help would be appreciated as I haven't progressed on this in 2 weeks. Any other questions let me know.

Here is where I am trying to load the pacman

```
   private void mapPictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    g.DrawImage(pacmanImage[currentMouthPosition], xPosition, yPosition, 32, 32);
}

//load event
private void Gameboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //load images
    pacmanImage[0] = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\Peter\\Documents\\PacmanGame\\PacMan_Game\\PacMan_Game\\images\\pac32_left_close.png");
    pacmanImage[1] = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\Peter\\Documents\\PacmanGame\\PacMan_Game\\PacMan_Game\\level1.txt\\pac32_left_open.png");
    pacmanImage[2] = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\Peter\\Documents\\PacmanGame\\PacMan_Game\\PacMan_Game\\level1.txt\\pac32_left_wide.png");
    pacmanImage[3] = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\Peter\\Documents\\PacmanGame\\PacMan_Game\\PacMan_Game\\level1.txt\\pac32_left_widest.png");
}
```

then on down I try to call

```
mapPicturebox.Invalidate();
```

but it doesnt not exist in the current context.

Comment: Try to post the relevant parts; don't post long code, just where the errors arise. We will then ask for more, if necessary. Going to an external site and looking at a full solution is, at least imho asking too much..

Comment: Aplogies, I changed it.

Comment: OK. Doesn't look too bad, so far. With 'on down' you mean a KeyDown event? Of the Form or what? What is the exact error message ? Where is mapPicturebox declared?

Comment: Yes I have a keydown event which has up/down/eft/right and shifts the x/y position of the pacman by ten. "The name mapPictureBox does not exist in the current context". And its declared in the designer? "this.mapPictureBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();"

Comment: Are you using different forms?

Comment: No, I have one form called Gameboard.

Comment: This should be fixed first, imo: . "The name mapPictureBox does not exist in the current context" Do check this out; check the spelling etc..

Comment: I have tried. I am passing mapPictureBox as an argument to my MovingPacman constructor but it will not work... Still same error. I despair...

Comment: Don't. (Despair.) I asked where the mapPictureBox is delared. You created it in the deisgner, sure. But you wrote that you pass a refernce to it in the MovingPacman constructor. So, what do you do with this refence? Do you store it in a class variable?

Comment: Got it working. Still a lot of stuff to do but this is a good start. Thanks man :)